# Get origin master and PR commit ID in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have the following piece code in a groovy script to get the origin/master current commit ID, and then the current pull request latest commit ID from a bitbucket repository

```
TARGET_COMMIT=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse origin/master^{commit}").trim()
SOURCE_COMMIT=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse pull-requests/" + env.BRANCH_NAME + "/from^{commit}").trim()
COMMIT_RANGE="$TARGET_COMMIT...$SOURCE_COMMIT"
```

This first line works when ran in my local machine, but fails in Jenkins, and I get

```
+ git rev-parse origin/master^{commit}
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master^{commit}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Changing the script to use `git rev-parse upstream/master^{commit}` works in Jenkins, but fails locally with the same error.

The second command for `SOURCE_COMMIT` fails both locally and in Jenkins..

This setup was working fine, but I believe Bitbucket made some updates that broke this syntax.

Is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: Try to refer to commits by their true names, which are their hash IDs, rather than by branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and other aliases. CI systems should provide and use raw hash IDs wherever possible, because those *work*, while the names may or may not work depending on who set which names.

Comment: @torek, that BRANCH_NAME actually returns the PR number. Which I am using to get the commit ID, I dont know any other way to get the last commit ID of the current Pull request?

Comment: Having a variable named `BRANCH_NAME` holding a simple number like `1690` seems fundamentally wrong, but then, Jenkins itself also seems fundamentally wrong, so I suppose that could go together. In any case you're using Jenkins (which I hate) and Bitbucket (which I don't use and have no opinion of one way or another) so I'm just giving general advice here, not anything specific to answering this specific questino.

Comment: @torek it's not my repo, nor my pipeline.. I am just trying to hotfix this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets try to figure it out.

```
TARGET = git rev-parse origin/master^{commit}
SOURCE = git rev-parse pull-requests/BRANCH/from^{commit}
RANGE = git log $TARGET...$SOURCE
```

### TARGET

The key points in these git commands are remote name/alias and branches/refs
You have next remote names (repository named locally on your machine or Jenkins runner).

You can call `git remote -vv` to see all your remotes.
You have **origin** at your local machine and **pull-requests** on Jenkins runner. It was first one (**origin**/master)

The next one is **branch name** (origin/**master**). If remote repository has next ref - <*origin/master*>, it could be received on your local machine or Jenkins runner by **git clone, git fetch, git pull [--rebase]**
Otherwise you could get next message, like this:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '<remote>/<ref>^{commit}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

### SOURCE

The same as **TARGET**, and you need to make sure that remote repository really has "branch" `pull-requests/BRANCH/from`

### COMMIT_RANGE

Just calls like this: `git log --oneline TARGET...SOURCE`
It returns you delta between TARGET and SOURCE include last commits from **origin/master** and **pull-requests/BRANCH/from** branches

I don't know what exactly you are trying to archive but I'll assume that just merge or check commit before merging.

1. You should to check your Job's parameters (source branches, etc.)
2. Check remote repository refs
3. I do recommend to use API to get last commits from refs (it won't require cloning the whole repository)

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I appreciate your time. When i try this `git remote -vv` I get 
origin ssh://git@serverName:portNumber/namespace/repoName.git (fetch)
origin ssh://git@serverName:portNumber/namespace/repoName.git (push)
upstream ssh://git@serverName:portNumber/namespace/repoName.git (fetch)
upstream ssh://git@serverName:portNumber/namespace/repoName.git (push)

Comment: So from what I can see, shouldnt that `origin/master` work since I have the origin remote name

Comment: If I do `git ls-remote origin` , I can see in the list `refs/pull-requests/1690/from`

Comment: Where are you doing `git ls-remote origin` ?
This command returns you all refs on remote side.

I think you should do `sh("printenv")` in your Jenkins pipeline and make sure that env.BRANCH_NAME exactly has value 1690 (PR ID) instead branch_name.

Comment: I did `git ls-remote origin` locally. But from your answer you asked me to check `git remote -vv`, which I pasted in the comment above, does that not give enough information to know how to get the latest commit in this pull request?

Comment: Pull request a.k.a Merge request it's just a process.
In your case, it's also ref name, you can get last commit from branch with `git pull <remote_name> <remote_branch>`

Comment: I only want to get the commit ID to use for SOURCE_COMMIT... and the whole issue is me not knowing what remote_name in Jenkins process is. I dont want to pull the code.